# Changing width of UISlider programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uislider

I am creating a `UISlider` programmatically. When initializing it, I use `initWithFrame` and pass in `CGRect` and it doesn't have any effect. I thought maybe I can change it after I initialize but still nothing...I can change it via I.B. so there's got to be a way to change it's width.

Comment: Can you post the code where you initialize and modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely can specify the width of the slider by using initWithFrame or changing the bounds of it. There has to be something else going on here that's preventing it from working.

Comment: Could it be that it's inside a UIToolBar?

Comment: @user635064 very likely, instead of adding the slider to the toolbar directly, put it inside a UIBarButtonItem like: `UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)];
    UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:slider];
    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:item];
    [self.toolbar setItems:items];`